# Move MySQL DBs between installations without client

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I need to move my MySQL databases and settings from an older installation of Xampp to my new one.

I'd like to duplicate everything, this includes all the custom settings I've made over the times.

I have the old Xampp files, but cannot access the old DB through a client (phpmyadmin or otherwise) since I just have the files.

I tried copying the mysql folder into my new xampp installation, but this gives me a bunch of errors.

Is there an easy and safe way to copy mysql from one Xampp installation to another by just moving around files?

Comment: Yes. You can just copy the whole folder and then run "setup_xampp.bat". Everything xampp needs is inside that folder (unless you moved stuff around).

Comment: True, but I want to use the new xampp version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, useful to know.

My problem was not with the mysql folder, but with missing phpmyadmin configuration files.

I replaced the phpmyadmin folder in the new installation with the one from the old one, and voila.

This can potentially give problems between versions if there are changes.